# Using a .sed file and invoking it from a .bash file to find and replace a word with the current date, but an error keeps being prompt because of date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a .sed, .bash and .txt file

The x.bash file has this within it

```
#!/bin/bash

./y.sed "$1"
```

The z.txt file has this within it

```
<dstamp>
```

The y.sed file has this command to find and replace <dstamp> with the current date

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

s/<dstamp>/date '+%Y%m%d'/e
```

This works. It substitutes <dstamp> with the current date

However, the command doesn't work if there's another word preceding <dstamp> in my z.txt file, for example:

```
Date: <dstamp>
```

Running it gives this error:

```
./x.bash z.txt

sh: 1: Date:: not found
```

I'm assuming that what it's missing is the "/g" at the end of s///g. So, how could I also make this global? I.e. make "e" and "g" work together?

Additionally, anytime I modify this, as such

```
s/<dstamp>/date '+%Y%m%d'/e

s/<dstamp>/New date: date '+%Y%m%d'/e
```

It also prompts me with the same error:

```
sh: 1: Date:: not found
```

Technically two questions being asked, but any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e` executes the entire line. You need something like this instead:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
s/'/'\\''/g
s/%/%%/g
s/\(.*\)<dstamp>\(.*\)/date +'\1%Y%m%d\2'/e
```

It would be easier to have the output of `date` as the replacement string though:

```bash
sed "s/<dstamp>/$(date +%Y%m%d)/" z.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions were useful, especially the first one on the fourth line. I wasn't aware that I could "add" things within `%Y%m%d` such as a back-reference `\1%Y%m%d`

Comment: @John welcome. Keep in mind that things you "add" there are processed by both the shell spawned for executing `date` and `date` itself, so you need to escape characters that have special meanings to those programs. Hence the second and third lines.